# Degree of Division of polynomials $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ when $\deg(q(x)) > \deg(p(x))$

Tags: polynomials, rational-functions

I'm not sure how to find the degree of the ratio $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ of polynomials $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ when $\deg(q(x)) > \deg(p(x))$. I couldn't find an answer. For example, $\deg(p(x))=10$ and $\deg(q(x))=26$.
Intuitively the degree of the ratio should be $-\infty$, and the degree of the remainder should be $10$.

Want to be sure if I'm right.
Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The degree of a (univariate) polynomial is defined as the degree of the highest non-zero term (written in standard form as sum of monomials).  A ratio of polynomials is a rational function, and there is no definition of degree that immediately generalizes the degree of polynomials (unless the ratio happens to be an exact division).  Perhaps identifying the source of this problem would clarify how "degree" is meant here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly I think you are right.

In the case when the divisor has greater degree than the one we are diving, the Division Algorithm says that $p(X)=0.q(X)+ p(X)$, and so the quotient is $0$ and the remainder is $p(X)$.